# FIleUpload.hasfile returns always false even control not placed in update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am using fileupload Control to upload files and the control is not placed in update panel...when Searched for the error all suggested that to place

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" />
</Triggers>
```

But not using the control in update panel..please suggest the solution and would be appreciated

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Enabled="true" EnableTheming="true" EnableViewState="true" Width="223px" Height="23px" ToolTip="Upload File" />
```